# Click to add marker as well as open an editable text box on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps, marker

I'm trying to create fullscreen google maps where a user can simply click on a location to add a marker and with that marker add a comment.

At the moment I have the click to place the marker working, but I can't seem to get the adding comment part.

Any idea how to get this working? I'm using HTML/JS

Comment: Try posting the code you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "Marker comment" you mean something like [Info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple), then try following snippet:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var result = prompt("Enter a value of comment for Marker.");
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: true,
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map
    });
    attachMessage(marker, result);
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
  });

 function attachMessage(marker, message) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: message
  });        
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
 }
```

It will popup the input window and use the entered text as value for `InfoWindow`.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87v0obb4/8/